# OAuth2 Token PHP

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I need to connect with an API that is using oAuth2.
I have never used oAuth2 before and im not really sure how to.
The provider is giving this information:

Obtaining an access token is done by sending an HTTP POST request to the above endpoint. The request should contain the following headers:

```
Authorization: Basic [client_id]:[client_secret]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Where `[client_id]` and `[client_secret]` should be replaced with your information. The composed `[client_id]:[client_secret]` string should be base64 encoded.

The header should look something like this:

```
Authorization: Basic bXlfY2xpZW50X2lkOnBFUnkyTGhLYko0U2FkY3ZLcklpQW5xWnprakg5bm9STUc3aUxZcWl2MA==
```

Finally, you need the following request body:

```
grant_type=password&scope=read write&username=[username]&password=[password]
```

Where [username] and [password] should be replaced with your credentials. If you are accessing the API with an API-key you should replace both [username] and [password] with the API-key obtained above.

If your request was composed correctly, and your credentials were correct, the server will return an access_token in JSON format for you to use:

```
{
    "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9(...)",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expires_in":3600,
    "refresh_token":null
}
```

What I tried is the following, but it returns an invalid request message:

```
    $api = "KEY GOES HERE";
$authurl = "https://url.com/oauth/token";

$client_id = "ID GOES HERE";
$client_secret = "SECRET GOES HERE";

// Creating base 64 encoded authkey
$Auth_Key = $client_id.":".$client_secret;
$encoded_Auth_Key=base64_encode($Auth_Key);

$headers = array();
$headers['Authorization'] = "Basic ".$encoded_Auth_Key;
$headers['Content-Type'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

$data = "grant_type=password&scope=read write&username=".$api."&password=".$api."";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $authurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);

$auth = curl_exec( $ch );

if ( curl_errno( $ch ) ){
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
}
curl_close($ch);

$secret = json_decode($auth);
$access_key = $secret->access_token;
```

Comment: Let us show the exact error message.

Comment: All I get is this: { "error": "invalid_request" }

Comment: why you have used username & password =api key?

Comment: Because of the instructions from the provider. They wrote this:  If you are accessing the API with an API-key you should replace both [username] and [password] with the API-key obtained above.

So what I understand is to use the key for username and password?

Comment: Are you able to share where you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Dinero - A danish bookkeeping system. https://api.dinero.dk/docs

Comment: I believe your headers have to be provided as an array of strings rather then a key value array for it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your code looks good except the POST field data.
The problem is that your query string is already encoded.
When you call `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));`, then it is encoded again.

I recommend you to set the variable `$data` as an array:

```
$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'password',
    'scope'      => 'read write',
    'username'   => $api,
    'password'   => $api,
);
```

The query string will be correctly encoded when `http_build_query` is called.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me. Please try with this piece of code to get token:

```
$base_url = 'https://example.com/oauth/token';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'client_id'     => YOUR-CLIENT-ID,
        'client_secret' => YOUR-CLIENT-SECRET,
        'username'      => YOUR-USERNAME-OR-EMAIL,
        'password'      => YOUR-PASSWORD,
        'grant_type'    => 'password'
));

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$auth_string = json_decode($data, true); // token will be with in this json
```

After getting the access token, you have to use this token in the header for your next request. It can be get, post, put or something else.

**GOOD LUCK**

Comment: This almost worked, but I needed to send the client_id and client_secret as base64 headers

Answer (score 1):

OAuth2.0 works on very simple principle, Hit the OAuth server get the token, pass the token to Resource server, Resource server validates the token and give the details/data.

So, to get the token check the following piece of code

```
$ch_curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch_curl, CURLOPT_URL, "endpoint url");
curl_setopt($ch_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch_curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type = your grant_type");
curl_setopt($ch_curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);   
 
$headers = array(); 
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
// base64_encode client id and password
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic ABCDEFGHIJKLM123456"; 
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch_curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$token = curl_exec($ch_curl);
echo $token;
curl_close($ch_curl);
```

which will return the response which you're looking it.

Comment: echo doesn't print anything for me in this example but the headers code in here got me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

Combining all the answers here led me to this working code.

The token will be in the $auth array

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $base_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(        
    'grant_type'    => 'client_credentials',    # https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/        
    'scope'         => $scope,  
)));

$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($client_id . ":" . $client_secret);
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
$auth = json_decode($data, true); // token will be with in this json

var_dump( $auth );
```